# Why doesn't this RegExp work as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, capturing-group

I made a `RegExp` to format an incoming date string, but it doesn't work as expected with my usage. I was hoping someone could explain why not:

```js
var data = [
  "m_2013_01_01",
  "m_2013_02_01",
  "m_2013_03_01",
  "m_2013_04_01"
];

// why aren't these equivalent?
//  expected
console.log(data.map(datum => datum.replace(/^m_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/g, '$1-$2-$3')));
//  ???
console.log(data.map(datum => datum.replace(/^m_(?:(\d+)_?){3}$/g, '$1-$2-$3')));
```

Comment: You should never use quantifiers on capturing groups, if you actually want to use them in any way, as only the last occurence of this group is actually stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the fist regex you are using 3 groups:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

That's why you can reference group 1, 2 and 3.

However, in the second regex you are using 1 group repeated multiple time, so group 2 and 3 doesn't exist and can't be referenced:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Whoa! Where did you get these control flows?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza Actually Debuggex has a share feature specifically for Stack Overflow which also links to Debuggex.

Comment: @Xufox, yes, I didn't want to paste the full debuggex share feature. The image was just ilustrative to answer the question

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, also... keep in mind that you can debug step by step the regex by using the slider ![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/LBmrtfB1CfRVnLoZ.png)